# How to make a variable that can only be deleted if I clear cache in browser? cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm thinking of using cookie, but is there any other option regarding this matter? I only want to set a variable for each pc so I can Prompt them a welcome message. Thank you in advance

Comment: If you want data to persist, then cookies and sessions are the only two options. And sessions use cookies. If there's any kind of security concern about the data, you put it in the session.

Comment: @GregSchmidt ok. Thanks for answering :)